# What are most common condition for reduction of hematite to magnetite?

Tags: redox, environmental-chemistry, magnetism

I found that hydrogen can reduce $\ce{Fe2O3}$ to $\ce{Fe3O4}$ under anaerobic conditions, but since I dont have $\ce{H2}$ in my lab what should I use to convert hematite into magnetite? and what conditions are used - temperature, pressure, partial pressure of oxygen and other important factors.
[image]

Comment: There is an old saw "If you have to ask how much it costs, you can't afford it." This is an analogous situation. Such chemistry would only happen under exotic conditions. If you have to ask what such conditions are, then you don't have sufficient knowledge to undertake such an experiment SAFELY.

Comment: We only have Argon and CO2 I am not sure why you think Argon is dangerous? It is inert gas so I dont understand your opint?